# Checkbox for showing and hiding all markers in driving directions in Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Thanks for any help you can provide! I've reviewed these links, but I haven't been able to translate these examples into a solution for my code (I'm still learning a lot about JS and Google Maps):

- [What is the difference between "marker.setVisible(false)" and "marker.setMap(null)" in Google Maps v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647711/what-is-the-difference-between-marker-setvisiblefalse-and-marker-setmapnul)
- [Toggle hide/show Google map markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141865/toggle-hide-show-google-map-markers) ,
- http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/12/1/Simple-Google-Maps-demo-with-Custom-Markers
- http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html

I just want a checkbox that, when checked, shows the markers in my array (arrMarkers). When the checkbox is unchecked, I want to be able to toggle the markers to hidden. I do not want this code to affect the markers in my driving directions.

Below is my latest attempt at it. It doesn't result in any errors, but the checkbox isn't doing anything to the markers:

```
    <script>
        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var map;

    function initialize() {
          CODE            
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
          $.getJSON( "CODE", {}, function( data ) {
          CODE
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(CODE),
        map: map,
    });
    arrMarkers = marker;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "CODE"
    });
    arrInfoWindows = infowindow;
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    function MapAll () {
    if (document.getElementById("mapall").checked) {
          arrMarkers.setVisible(true);
          }
          else  {
          arrMarkers.setVisible(false);
          };
    }
    document.getElementById("mapall).onchange = MapAll;
    CODE
    </script>
```

** Edit 1 **

By replacing my JSON object with markers that I click to add (using @bnz's solution), I was able to get the markers to show / hide. Now, I need to be able to add the markers just with my JSON object. My updated code is below, but it gives an error: "arrMarkers.push is not a function". When I delete that line of code, the map loads the markers, but the checkbox doesn't do anything.

```
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;

    function initialize() {
      CODE

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
      var arrMarkers = [];

      $.getJSON( "CODE", {}, function( data ) {
      $.each( data, function( i, item ) {
      var loc = item.masterlocation;
            $("#markers").append('<li><a href="#" rel="' + i + '">' + loc.nickname + '</a></li>');
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(+loc.latitude, +loc.longitude),
                map: map,
                title: loc.nickname,
            });
            arrMarkers = marker;
    arrMarkers.push(marker);

    function clearOverlays() {
      if (arrMarkers) {
    for( var i = 0, n = arrMarkers.length; i < n; ++i ) {
      arrMarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }
      }
    }

    function showOverlays() {
      if (arrMarkers) {
    for( var i = 0, n = arrMarkers.length; i < n; ++i ) {
      arrMarkers[i].setMap(map);
    }
      }
    }

    $('#mapall').change(function() {
     if($('#mapall').attr('checked')) {
      showOverlays();
      }
      else  {
      clearOverlays();
      }
    });
    });
    }

    function calcRoute() {
    CODE
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define a global marker array.

```
var arrMarkers = [];
```

Then add each marker to the array via push.

```
arrMarkers.push(marker);
```

Hide function

```
function clearOverlays() {
  if (arrMarkers) {
    for( var i = 0, n = arrMarkers.length; i < n; ++i ) {
      arrMarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
}
```

Show function

```
function showOverlays() {
  if (arrMarkers) {
    for( var i = 0, n = arrMarkers.length; i < n; ++i ) {
      arrMarkers[i].setMap(map);
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT:

Look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/mNh7A (w JQuery 1.4)

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/mNh7A/2/ (w JQuery 2)

EDIT 2:

Here is the JS code, HTML/ CSS on JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/jxzxF/

Now you only have to add / change the marker provider from manual to json feed.

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var arrMarkers = [];

function addMarker(location){
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
      });
arrMarkers.push(marker);
}

function clearOverlays() {
  if (arrMarkers) {
    for( var i = 0, n = arrMarkers.length; i < n; ++i ) {
      arrMarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
}

function showOverlays() {
  if (arrMarkers) {
    for( var i = 0, n = arrMarkers.length; i < n; ++i ) {
      arrMarkers[i].setMap(map);
    }
  }
}

$('#mapall').change(function() {
 if( $('#mapall').prop("checked")) {
          showOverlays();
          }
          else  {
          clearOverlays();
          }
});

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom:7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: chicago
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) 
      {
      addMarker(event.latLng);
      });      
}

$('#end').change( function(){
  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  var request = {
      origin:start,
      destination:end,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, @bnz. How do I toggle (show / hide) the markers with a checkbox using these functions?

Comment: In your MapAll() function, change arrMarkers.setVisible(true); to showOverlays(); and arrMarkers.setVisible(false); to clearOverlays().

Comment: i have added a fiddle to the answer, i hope it helps you - it shows / hides all markers - when a select box is checked or not.

Comment: BNZ, thanks for taking the time to create the fiddle! I've updated the question to show where things stand: I'm just not sure how to get your solution to work with my JSON-loaded markers. Also, I haven't gotten to this step yet, but will your solution ignore the markers in the driving directions? I only want to show and hide the markers in my JSON object. THanks!

Comment: Where do you get the json data? You just have to use 2 arrays, one for your json data and one for your directions. Can you share more code, pls?

Comment: @KDP look at my latest edit, you can what you want, pls change the marker provider to your json feed - or give the url if possible and i will add it.